# Updating a blob column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, blob

How to update a BLOB column in SQL Server 2008, I am trying to do a pattern match with Like and would like to update the column.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_read_write_blob.html:

```
// Read Image into Byte Array from Filesystem
byte[] photo = GetPhoto(photoFilePath);

// Construct INSERT Command
SqlCommand addEmp = new SqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO Employees ("+
    "LastName,FirstName,Title,HireDate,ReportsTo,Photo) "+
    "VALUES(@LastName,@FirstName,@Title,@HireDate,@ReportsTo,@Photo)",_conn);

addEmp.Parameters.Add("@LastName",  SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = plastName;
addEmp.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = pfirstName;
addEmp.Parameters.Add("@Title",     SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = ptitle;
addEmp.Parameters.Add("@HireDate",  SqlDbType.DateTime).Value     = phireDate;
addEmp.Parameters.Add("@ReportsTo", SqlDbType.Int).Value          = preportsTo;
addEmp.Parameters.Add("@Photo",     SqlDbType.Image, photo.Length).Value = photo;

// Open the Connection and INSERT the BLOB into the Database
_conn.Open();
addEmp.ExecuteNonQuery();
_conn.Close();



// **** Read Image into Byte Array from Filesystem
public static byte[] GetPhoto(string filePath)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

    byte[] photo = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);

    br.Close();
    fs.Close();

    return photo;
}
```

You can do full-text search if your documents are:

```
.doc 
.txt 
.xls 
.ppt 
.htm
```

Refer:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917636.aspx

Comment: And how does that allow you to search a blob for a certain pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Updating a blob is no problem, you just update it.  "I am trying to do a pattern match with Like and would like to update the column." That is not possible.  You can't search blobs.  There are complicated workarounds.  You could enable full text search is probably the easiest.  If you have a toy database and don't really need blobs in the first place, you could cast it as nvarchar(4000) and search that, which will do the cast row by row, do a painfully slow search, and only work if what you're looking for is in the first 4000 characters.